# Identifying coordinate system of historical map for Arctic Ocean?

Tags: coordinate-system, georeferencing, historical-maps, arctic

I have a historical map (Arctic Ocean) with unknown CRS system.

[image: This is the Arctic Ocean]

In order to compare it with my results, I have to merge them somehow.

Could someone suggest the closest possible coordinate reference system in which the map was made or how I could merge my raster with it?

Comment: Perhaps review earlier Q&As on Arctic coordinate systems: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arctic+coordinate-system

Comment: Without knowing the original coordinate system used, you can georeference the image using known control points in the coordinate system of your other dataset. Most GIS software can do this georeferencing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a wild guess, to me it looks similar to a **Lambert azimuthal equal-area projection**, rotated 80 degrees (I mean, looking from N80E toward N100W direction).

[image]

(Above: North Pole area by QGIS 3.8 on `EPSG:102017 North_Pole_Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area`, rotating 80.0 degrees).